# Can Sessions conflict when encapsulated in a static class static property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

I have an ASP.NET application that is accessed by 120-140 users at the same time on average. I use Session to get and set user specific info. To make things easy I've got a static a class called `CurrentSession` and it has a property called `UserInfo`:

```
public static class CurrentSession{
     public static UserInfo{
          get{return HttpContext.Current.Session["userInfo"]!=null?(UserInfo)HttpContext.Current.Session["userInfo"]:null;}
          set{HttpContext.Current.Session["userInfo"]=value;}
     }
    //And other properties
}
```

And whenever I needed current user's info I just used to do:

```
CurrentSession.UserInfo;
```

Recently I've come across situations when wrong user info is retrieved. Is there a problem in my approach that can cause `Session` conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It can't be that the session change can be caused by the `static` method. In fact, `HttpContext.Current` itself is a `static`. Assigning it to a static variable can cause this.

Comment: @Farid: Did you confirm the origin of the issue?

Comment: Dear @Patrick Hofman, I also think so and was sure this was not the case. I just wanted to make sure I had no problem with my approach. In fact there was no problem in the code. It was a result of one person accessing the application on behalf of many others. So it was not a conflict.

Comment: @FaridImranov: Okay. Glad you found it.